# awk parsing output and extracting values

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I need to process output that looks as below:

```
my_first_key: {i}text
my_first_key: {j}different_text
my_first_key: {k}some_text
my_second_key: value1
my_first_key: {l}some_text
my_second_key: value2
```

Lines always begin with one of two keys followed by `:` then a space then either an index in curly braces for one key, or immediately a value for the second key. A line with the second-type key and the value is always preceded by a line with first key and the index.

I need two functions:

1. `array()`: to return the array as `{k:value1, l:value2}`.
2. `index(value)` to return the index value from the preceding line so `index(value2)` returns `l`.

I see examples to return line numbers etc., but my `awk` level is 0.

[From Moshe comment] Algorithm is like this:

```
a) awk '/$value/{ print NR; exit }'
b) awk 'NR==$(previous_return - 1)
c) awk '{split($0,a,"{}") | print a[2]
```

Comment: What is your expected output from above sample?

Comment: depending on which function is invoked. array() will return {k:value1, l:value2}. it could be two lines $index:$value or whatever. index(value1) returns 'k' and index(value2) returns 'l' etc.

Comment: Yes, to echo anubhava, please edit your question to add for each function the expected output, and please be sure it's the exact output you expect from the input you've already posted.

Comment: Your awk level is 0. Fine. Show how you would write the program in pseudo-code for whatever language you are familiar with and we can translate it to awk for you. Makes our lives easier than if we have to come up with the algorithm for you too.

Comment: Algorithm is like this: a) awk '/$value/{ print NR; exit }' b) awk 'NR==$(previous_return - 1) c) awk '{split($0,a,"{}") | print a[2]

Comment: @MosheShmukler don't provide information in comments, edit your question to provide all information. I'll do this edit for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have too much time for now, but the following program should help you solve the first point. It is strictly based on your example. From your example input, I replaced alphabetic indexes i,j,k and l with 1,2,3,4, so the test file contains :

```
*my_first_key: {1}text
my_first_key: {2}different_text
my_first_key: {3}some_text
my_second_key: value1
my_first_key: {4}some_text
my_second_key: value2*
```

and the program is :

```
BEGIN {
  # split on braces to have the index from my_first_key: in field #2 without effort
  FS="[{}]"
}
/^my_first_key:/ { ix=$2}
/^my_second_key:/ {
  sub(/^my_second_key: */, "") # leaves only value2 in $0
  if (first_done==0) {
    buffer["index1"]=ix
    buffer["value1"]= $0
    first_done=1
  }
  else { # first_done == 1
    printf ("{%s:%s, %s:%s}\n", buffer["index1"], buffer["value1"], ix, $0)
    first_done=0
  }
}
```

and the output is:

```
awk -f example.awk test.data
{3:value1, 4:value2}
```

Comment: You are obviously a genius, in addition to being a very generous person. I am going to allocate time to understand what you did, after I get the rest of project working. At this point, I only partially understand why your example functions as needed. It does work, indeed. Thank you, again.

Comment: @MosheShmukler:  To reiterate points made in comments: First learn that the best questions on S.O. include 1. small set of sample data covering expected cases and 1 or 2 error cases, 2. Expected output from the "expected case" data, 3. your attempt to solve your problem, either in code, or p-code, 4. your current output including exact error messages (but reasonable length), 5. versions of OS and utilities being used, if they are not super standard Linux (bash V > 3, etc) 6. Any other relevant info ("I've already tried X,Y,Z and they didn't work"). Good luck!